# Is it possible to get all devices and their name in a local network with flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I wan't to build an app that detects devices with specific names in my network and which gives me the ip-addresses of these devices.
Is there any package which would help me with my problem or is there any solution?

I tried finding the device by running a Webserver on it, which has a "/status" path and a "/device" path. But it took ages to verify.
I just want to quickly scan my network und return the ip-addresses.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

by using dart io

good starting point for you

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
// Get the local IP address of the device.
 String localIP = await InternetAddress.anyIPv4.address;

   // Get the network prefix (e.g., "192.168.1").
   String networkPrefix = localIP.substring(0, localIP.lastIndexOf('.'));

// Create a list of IP addresses to scan.
List<String> ipAddresses = [];
for (int i = 1; i <= 255; i++) {
ipAddresses.add('$networkPrefix.$i');
}

// Scan the network for devices with specific names.
List<String> deviceIPAddresses = [];
for (String ipAddress in ipAddresses) {
// Try to connect to the device at the IP address.
try {
  Socket.connect(ipAddress, 80).then((socket) {
    // Send an HTTP request to the device.
    socket.write('GET /status HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n');

    // Read the response from the device.
    socket.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((response) {
      // Check if the device has a specific name.
      if (response.contains('DEVICE_NAME')) {
        // Add the device's IP address to the list.
        deviceIPAddresses.add(ipAddress);
      }
    });
  });
} catch (e) {
  // Ignore any errors.
}
  }

// Do something with the list of device IP addresses (e.g., display it on the screen).
}
```